# Why I am getting package not found error?

Tags: java, javac

I have created two java files `A.java` and `B.java`. Both classes are in same folder `testjava`.

**Code in A.java**

```
package pkg;

public class A{
    int data;
    public void printer(){
        System.out.println("I'm in A");
    }
}
```

**Code in B.java**

```
package mypkg;
import pkg.*;

public class B{
    void printer(){
        System.out.println("I'm in B");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A obj = new A();
        obj.printer();      
    }
}
```

To compile first file I used:
 `javac -d . A.java`
which compiled with no errors and created `A.class` in `./pkg` folder

To compile second file I am using `javac -cp "./pkg" B.java` which gives me the following errors:
[image: Error Image]

My directory structure after compilation of `A.java`:
[image: After A.java compilation]

What should include as my `classpath`? I have read and tried other StackOverflow questions on the same topic but couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Please no images of text, code or error messages.

Comment: The package path like a.b.c relates to a directory path a/b/c/. So you have to create subdirectories pkg and mypkig.

Comment: When you compile with `-d .`, the directory `.` is the target and hence, the classpath for subsequent operations. So don’t use `-cp "./pkg"` but `-cp .` Just being consistent helps a lot…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your project directory looks like this:

```
project| tree
.
├── mypkg
│   └── B.java
└── pkg
    └── A.java
```

you should compile `A` like this:

```
javac pkg/A.java
```

and `B` with

```
javac mypkg/B.java
```

you should do this from the project directory. After you compile, the directory structure looks like this:

```
project| tree
.
├── mypkg
│   ├── B.class
│   └── B.java
└── pkg
    ├── A.class
    └── A.java
```

BTW, you have a syntax error in your code, should be `obj.printer();` instead of `A.printer();`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!! I have corrected my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method printer() from the type A.
You are calling the instance method "printer()" from the static area.

Comment: Thanks for the input, corrected my error